# How do I insert a <p> tag into an ASP CheckBoxList's Checkboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a CheckBoxList that I am dynamically adding ListItems to in code-behind. It is defined as follows in the .ascx file:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="cbl" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" RepeatLayout="UnorderedList"></asp:CheckBoxList>
```

This produces HTML that looks like this:

```
<ul id="cbl">
    <li>
       <input id="cbl_0" type="checkbox" name="M$content$PCDZ$M5TOPBM$ctl00$cbl$cbl_0" value="value">
       <label for="cbl_0">label</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Is it possible to insert a p-tag into the rendered html from the code-behind like so?

```
<ul id="cbl">
    <li>
        <p class="checkbox">
            <input id="cbl_0" type="checkbox" name="M$content$PCDZ$M5TOPBM$ctl00$cbl$cbl_0" value="value">
            <label for="cbl_0">label</label>
        </p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Just add it however your adding the checkbox.

Comment: @Scath I am adding checkboxes like so: `cbl.Items.Add(new ListItem("label", "value"));` How should I indicate that there should be a <p> tag around the checkbox?

Comment: Not sure but "<p class="checkbox"> label", "value </p>" might work